# How can I use OOP here: I need to avoid re-instantiating an object

Tags: java, oop

I want to avoid having to keep re-instantiating objects. Here's an example of what I have:

**A class which handles**

- Errors.
- Logging.
- Orders
- Emailing
- Database stuff.
- Updates prices
- And more...

Now in the classes: 'Orders, emailing, database, price updater' I need to have a logger & error handler class instantiated with the order id & customer id from the class Orders.

Now I could keep on creating new objects of Orders & new objects of logger & error handler in every class but that seems unnecessary, or is that normal?

I almost forgot to mention, this will be an automated software running on a server. So it's inside a loop. Gets orders, processes it, emails and so on.

I'm a self-taught 'coder' so please forgive me if I miss blatant stuff. I'm stepping over from functional to object oriented programming style.

All the best!

Comment: It sounds like you want dependency injection.

Comment: *"Now in the classes...I need to have a logger & error handler class instantiated with the order id & customer id from the class Orders."* Why do your logger and error handler need to know the order ID and customer ID?

Comment: It would probably be useful to include pseudocode of what you're doing for clarity (sort of the way I have in my answer).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder My logger uses the order ID and customer ID as the path of the log file.

Comment: @SLaks thankyou, I think that's it. I'll look into it. No idea why my posts get negative points always. It's a proper question no? Stackoverflow is really not friendly heh.

Answer (score 0):

> So it's inside a loop. Gets orders, processes it, emails and so on.

If it's really true that your logger and error handler need to know the order ID and customer ID, then you could provide mutator methods on those classes allowing you to set the ID. Then you'd only need one instance of each of them, which you'd update within the loop:

```
Logger logger = /*...create or acquire the logger...*/;
ErrorHandler errHandler = /*...create or acquire the error handler...*/;
for (Order order : orders) {
    logger.setOrderInfo(order.id, order.customerId);
    errHandler.setOrderInfo(order.id, order.customerId);

    // ...handle the order...
}
```

You might even pass them the `Order`, although that ties them even more tightly than the above does.

If you're doing this so they can include information about the order and customer when logging/handling errors, you might consider generalizing that information so they don't know about order and customer IDs per se, they just know a piece of information that they need to include in logs/error reports.